# Passing "el" inside jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

This is obviously very common, I cannot find a clear explanation of passing "el" inside a function.

I just really want to fully wrap my head around it, I am getting much better at jQuery it's exciting but I want to understand this more.

I toyed with using "e" or "event" inside an event function and understand it to a degree.

EX:

```
    jQuery('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('<div/>').append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented').appendTo('#log2');

    });
```

This returns this string of text "default click prevented" so I now understand why you pass `event` it's so you can refer to the event inside. right?

Well that makes sense, I still need more practice with that, but I am not sure about "el" at all.

Ex: if I wrote a function like this.

```
    var app = {
        add: function (el) {
            $('<div/>').append('default ' + el.type + ' prevented').appendTo('#log1');
        }
    }

    jQuery('.add').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        app.add(this);
    });
```

Obviously thats wrong because "el" is not a "type" but I am trying to play with it to wrap my head around it, is it to get the index of an object?

I may have better luck if I knew what this method is called because I am having trouble finding information on this due to lack of terminology. I know the first example is "passing an elements event" not so sure when its like this, pretty sure its to refer to the object or something?

Here is a fiddle maybe you can modify it so I can study it [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVkDM/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`el` usually means element(s), and `el.type` would get the element type, like `text`, `number` etc. if the element looked like :

```
<input type="text" />
```

so it's a reference to a DOM nodelist/element in most cases, but it's just a variable, so it could mean anything, but in this case it's clearly a DOM element being passed in :

```
app.add(this);
```

Comment: Nope, it's common amongst developers to shorten `event` to `e` and element to `el`.

Comment: one more question of curiosity shouldnt http://jsfiddle.net/pVkDM/2/ pass the element type, which is a div? Sorry if something flew over my head.

Comment: I see that it does pass in the console log.. Now I completely understand el.. just need to figure out how to use it properly.. I kinda sorta think I know..

Well this is tough I think both these answers helped me together

Answer (score 1):

You are passing DOM object. `this` in the code refers to

```
<a class="add" href="#">Add</a>
```

Try below code snippet to catch event type:

```
jQuery('.add').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        app.add(e);
    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pVkDM/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Ok I understand now why you should pass 'e' like you did, in the live code, I actually need to refer to (this) Im not referring or catching the event type in the live code, but due to my example this works great and helps me understand it a little more.

Comment: I just modified your code to catch event type. If you would liek to pass element use `this` and if you would like to pass event use `e`.

Comment: Yeah using `this` returns nothing, I am curious to know why it's not passing the element.type? shouldnt this http://jsfiddle.net/pVkDM/2/ be returning the element type which is a div?

Comment: i see it passing in the console log now. I didnt realize until now you added that :) This deserves more 1+ Its hard to choose which answer to go with, but both you guys really helped me wrap my head around el.. THANKS so much man !

Comment: Hey no issues.. adeno answered 2 mins before me. So he deserves it. :) Accept his answer.

Comment: Very noble of you... I wanted to choose this because that dude has so much rep, but he deserves it, as well as I think you do.. thanks again for helping me understand. I am playing with jsfiddle and the console log, its really starting to make sense now... :)